# Sending multiple emails using emails retrivied from a database column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to write a windows form App where-in I need to send an email to a list of users. The users list is returned/retrieved from a database table. I can send an email to one user but I'm not able to replicate/use the same logic on multiple users.

here's the code I have used to send an email to a single user:

```
class MailModule
    {
        public static void CreateMessage(string Server, int Port, string From, string to, string Subject, string Body)
        {


            System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(From, to, Subject, Body);
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Server);
            client.Port = Port;
            client.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
            try
            {

                client.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("Shout Sent", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                message.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                MessageBox.Show(message.DeliveryNotificationOptions.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to send the *same* message to muliple recipients.

Instead of using the `MailMessage` constructor, use the `To` collection to add multiple addresses.

```
class MailModule
{
    public static void CreateMessage(string Server, int Port, string From, IList<string> to, string Subject, string Body)
    {


        System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        var message = new MailMessage();

        message.From = new MailAddress(From);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        to.ForEach(x => message.To.Add(x));

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Server);
        client.Port = Port;
        client.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
        try
        {

            client.Send(message);
            MessageBox.Show("Shout Sent", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            message.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            MessageBox.Show(message.DeliveryNotificationOptions.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi thread for sending message:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var mailTo in mailList)
{
   var task =  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateMessage(server, port, from, mailTo, subject, body);

   tasks.Add(task);
}

// You can wait till all tasks are done
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need set some delay between each attempt to send e-mail, because server can't send so many emails for such time.